# Good alternatives to Omnidazzle?

Tags: screen-casting, podcast

Does anyone know of a good pen software that allows you to draw on the screen? kind of similar to omnidazzle ?

Answer (score 1):

here are couple of sites you should check out:

1.http://epic-pen.com/

2.http://ink2go.org/

3.https://www.pencilkings.com/drawing-tools-and-drawing-software/

hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Hi Lea, thank you so much for the response. When I followed the epic-pen.com link you sent I get the following script after downloading: MZP
4‘@3“ã¬¿çD¡ãââBÉ˙duÏããâ^[√êââ@√ã¿SVãÚãÿËùˇˇˇÖ¿u3¿^[√ãâPãVâPãââXâBâ∞^[√ãPãâ
âQã8‘@â£8‘@√SVWUQãÒâ$ãËã]ã$ãâãPâVã;ãCã–S;uã√Ë∑ˇˇˇãCâãCFÎãV;¬u
ã√ËöˇˇˇãCFãﬂ;Îu¬ã÷ã≈ËUˇˇˇÑ¿u3¿âZ]_^[√ç@SVWUÉƒ¯ãÿã˚ã2ãC;rlãŒJãËk;Õw^;uãBCãB)CÉ{uDã√Ë5ˇˇˇÎ;ã

Answer (score 1):

**Presentify** is a simple mac app to let you draw on the screen. It has a whiteboard option and also highlights the cursor in different styles.

[image]

Website: https://presentify.compzets.com
App Store: https://apps.apple.com/app/presentify/id1507246666

*Disclosure: I am the developer of this app.*